# EF Core Loading Entities does not map to Query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing an API for generically handling Rest.  I'm having some trouble loading dependent entities.  I'm using .Net-Core 2.0

I’m trying to grab out the last message for each conversation. I have a method for loading a list of conversations which looks like so:

```
[HttpGet("Convo")]
public async Task<Conversation[]> LoadConversation()
{
   var query = this._context.Conversations.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
   var messages = await query.Select(x => x.Messages.OrderBy(m =>
                                      m.Created).FirstOrDefault())
                             .ToArrayAsync();

   var conversations = await query.ToArrayAsync();

   return conversations;
}
```

When I check the messages I have a message whose has a conversation Id of 3011,
When I check conversations, I have an Id Loaded of 3011. Yet, the conversation.Messages are still empty.

**EDIT**
I've also tried to load them using an anonymous select, which still didn't map either

```
var convo = await query.Select(x => new { 
   Conversation = x, 
   Message = x.Messages.OrderBy(m => m.Created).FirstOrDefault() 
}).ToArrayAsync();
```

**NOTE**

If I include all of my messages, they map fine

```
var conversationWithAllMessages = await query.Include(x => x.Messages).ToArrayAsync();
```

They also work if I call SelectMany on the Entire collection

```
var messages = query.SelectMany(x => x.Messages)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.ConversationId)
                    .ToArray();
```

But I only only want to include the last message

**EDIT**

[image]

Why aren't my entities mapping, How Can I Get My Entities to map appropriately?

Comment: This work fine and gives correct results.

Comment: @Smit are you using .Net-Core 2.0?

Comment: @johnny5 Smit is not using EF Core, he is developing it :)

Comment: @Smit that may be working in some cases, but perhaps not always, please look at the photo I've uploaded

Comment: @Smit,  This looks like a bug,  but maybe it's because I didn't read the full spec, but it looks like a single entity does not map to a collection, unless pulled out as a collection or IEnumerable

Comment: This looks somewhat similar to the issue I encountered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932792/ef-core-fix-up-when-querying-subset-of-columns. I think generally speaking EF Core doesn't handle well projection when it comes to mapping related entities.

Comment: @johnny5 - Thanks for screenshot. Now I understand query gave correct result but did not track it properly. I have filed issue on EF Core repo https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11762
As a work-around you could `Attach` messages to context manually and fixup will figure out navs.

Comment: @Smit I’ve worked around this by using SelectMany and Take, it seems like mapping when pulling a collection works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that, EFCore expects a Collection Or IEnumerable To be able to map to the Collection Property of My Parent Entity

Looks like this is a bug with EF-Core.  Maybe I'm overlooking the spec and only Collections should map to collections?  As a work around I resolved this with SelectMany and Take.

```
var messages =  query.SelectMany(x => x.Messages.OrderBy(m => m.Created).Take(1))
                     .OrderBy(x => x.ConversationId)
                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force includes with this syntax

```
var query = this._context.Conversations.Include("Messages").OrderBy(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t want to load all of the messages, only the last one. So the include syntax is not an option.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The query isn't run until .ToArrayAsync() is called, so you won't be getting all the messages.

Comment: @ChrisDixon How so? You can't filter include statements?  I only need the last message not all of them.  So all of your filters applied on the IQueryable will be on Conversation, and Not Messages.